# how to extract the rows where a group appears more than a certain number of times

Tags: sql

I have the following table

```
col1  col2  col3   key
A     B     C      1
A     B     B      2
A     B     B      3
A     B     D      4
B     D     C      5
```

I would like to extract the rows where the group col1, col2, col3 appears more than once in the table.

> ```
> A     B     B      2
> A     B     B      3
> ```

So far, I have:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, count(*)
FROM db.table
GROUP BY col1, col2, col3
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

> ```
> col1  col2  col3   count(*)
> A     B     B      2
> ```

Is there a way to extract those rows with A B B without having to join the final table with the initial table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use exists logic:

```sql
SELECT col1, col2, col3, "key"
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourTable t2
              WHERE t2.col1 = t1.col1 AND t2.col2 = t1.col2 AND
                    t2.col3 = t1.col3 AND
                    t2."key" <> t1."key");
```

Comment: Is `yourTable` the original table, or the result of `count(*) > 2 `statement?

Comment: Original table (if I understand your comment correctly).

Answer (score 0):

Try below query with `CTE`

```
with MyCTE
as
(
select col1,col2,col3,Key,COUNT(*) over(PARTITION BY col1,col2,col3 order 
by col1,col2,col3) as Duplicate from yourtable
)
select col1,col2,col3,key from MyCTE where Duplicate>1
```